# Show complex function is bijective

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to show that the function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus\{i\}$ given by
$f(z)=i\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ is bijective.

I get stuck very early on - I think I get thrown off by the fact that we're in $\mathbb{C}$ and not good old $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt:

**injective**: assuming $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$, I need to show $z_1=z_2$. Usually I would just set it up like this: $$i\frac{z_1+1}{z_1-1}=i\frac{z_2+1}{z_2-1} $$
And then manipulate the expressios to get $z_1=z_2$, but I can't seem to do it here.

Am I choosing a poor strategy here?

In regards to surjectivity, I am just lost.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can proceed in the same manner as you would with real numbers: Cancel the common factor $i$, cross multiply, cancel common expressions, ... Did you try it?

Comment: I suggest to also look up “Möbius transformation” – that are (analytic) bijective mappings from the extended complex plane to itself.

Comment: Adding to @MartinR 's comment: If you'd do it in $\mathbb R$, you'd only use the properties of fields anyway. And $\mathbb C$ is a field, too, so there's no reason not to do it the exact same way.

Comment: Thanks both! Much appreciated. I should just keep reminding myself to simply use the same techniques as in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you solve the equation$$i\frac{z+1}{z-1}=w,$$you will get$$z=\frac{w+i}{w-i}.$$So, define $g\colon\Bbb C\setminus\{i\}\longrightarrow\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}$ by$$g(z)=\frac{z+i}{z-i}$$and check that it is the inverse of $f$. In other words, check that$$(\forall z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{i\}):f\bigl(g(z)\bigr)=z\quad\text{and that}\quad(\forall z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}):g\bigl(f(z)\bigr)=z.$$

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. Do you think that such a strategy works better in general, when you want to show that some function is bijective? i.e. to just construct the inverse, rather than to check injectivity and surjectivity?

Comment: Yes, I most surely do.

Comment: Okay. I will keep this in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: And one more thing: the way $g$ was defined, it is actually automatic that $(\forall z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{i\}):f\bigl(g(z)\bigr)=z$.

Answer (score 1):

A broader context: your function is a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Definition) $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with$$a=b=c=-d=i\to ad-bc=2\ne0.$$These transformations are famously isomorphic to invertible $\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b\\c & d\end{array}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Writing $f(z)$ as
$$
f(z) = i\left (\frac{2}{z-1} + 1\right)
$$
shows that $f$ is the composition of bijective mappings:

- $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{1\} \to \Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\} , \, z \mapsto z - 1$,
- $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \to \Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\} , \, z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$,
- $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \to \Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\} , \, z \mapsto 2 \cdot z $,
- $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\} \to \Bbb{C}\setminus\{1\} , \, z \mapsto z + 1$,
- $\Bbb{C}\setminus\{1\} \to \Bbb{C}\setminus\{i\} , \, z \mapsto i \cdot z$

and therefore bijective.

Generally, every [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) is a [composition of simple transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Composition_of_simple_transformations) (translation, inversion/reflection, homothety/rotation), and therefore a bijective mapping from the [extended complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere) $\hat{\Bbb C} = \Bbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$ onto itself.